# Install ClassLoader component

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I want to install a 3rd party library and after searching I tryed to include this in *app/autolad.php*:

```
loader->registerNamespace('libMyLib', __DIR__.'/vendor/mylib/libmylib');
```

Which throws an error:

```
Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerNamespace()
```

Which searching looks like ClassLoader included in Symfony2 is not the same as [component ClassLoader](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader#readme), and you must install this component in order to include third party libraries using this method.

So, I try to follow the cryptic instructions to install this and looks like I need to install [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) (I'm under Windows), update my composer.json with these 2 lines (I made up the version number according to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/class-loader)):

```
"symfony/finder": "2.2.*",
"symfony/class-loader": "2.4.*",
```

And the execute `composer install` in my command line (just under symfony folder), I did and nothing happened, I get this message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. 
You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException] An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

So I'm more lost than when I began; how do I include a 3rd party lib? How do I install components?

Thanks

Comment: No luck `Package "symfony\component\classloader\universalclassloader" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/class-loader 2.4.* could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the class loader and registering manually the namespace, as the autoloader is generated by composer. But two options. Ask the developer to add a composer.json to the library and publish on packagist. Or include it yourself as a package repository in your composer.json described in the composer docs: http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

Edit: after changing something in the composer.json you need to run update and not install. As a hint ;-)

Comment: I had an error in version, packagist gives the correct line for composer.json: "symfony/class-loader": "v2.2.1"

Comment: Kk, but try it as package in composer.json and not adding it to the autoload.php as mixing two autoloader is not good. Composer projects using an generated composer autoloader.